# Combinations of boolean Values in a HashMap Java

Tags: java, algorithm, iteration, permutation

I have a hashmap(Integer, Boolean), and the keys go from 1...N. I'm trying to create a brute force method of going through every combination of booleans, the end complexity would be O(2^N). I'm using the keys as variables for my calculations so it is crucial the booleans in the hashmap change, and not be converted into an array.

So a hashmap of size 4 would be
1 False
2 False
3 False
4 False

next iteration would be
1 False
2 False
3 False
4 True

next iteration would be
1 False
2 False
3 True
4 False

and so on...

Comment: Where is your attempted code, example, and expected result?

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: Why not use a BitSet?

Comment: Note: look at the binary representation of your loop counter as it goes from 0 to 2^N

Comment: This is begging for Guava `Sets.powerSet()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that functionality by the following code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Map<Integer, Boolean>> bitmapList = generateBitMaps(3);

    for (Map<Integer, Boolean> bitmap : bitmapList) {
        System.out.println(bitmap);

    }

}

public static List<Map<Integer, Boolean>> generateBitMaps(int nBits) {
    int size = (int) Math.pow(2, nBits);
    List<Map<Integer, Boolean>> bitmapList = new ArrayList<>(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Map<Integer, Boolean> bitmap = new HashMap<>(nBits);

        int mask = size >> 1;
        int bitId= 1;
        while (mask > 0) {
            if ((mask & i) == 0) {
                bitmap.put(bitId, false);
            } else {
                bitmap.put(bitId, true);
            }
            mask = mask >> 1;
            ++bitId;
        }
        bitmapList.add(i, bitmap);
    }

    return bitmapList;

}
```

Points to note:

- The keys in the bitmap are in a way that 1 represents MSB and n represents the LSB as mentioned in the question.
- The time complexity is O(n * 2 ^ n). Idk if it's possible to do it in O(2^n) with maps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you want to brute force all numbers from `1...N` and check their binary representation. Why do you need to keep bits? It's enough just to have an integer, and you always will be able to convert it to a boolean array. The code below

```
public class BitPlay {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(toBinary(i, 2)));
        }
    }

    private static boolean[] toBinary(int number, int base) {
        final boolean[] ret = new boolean[base];
        for (int i = 0; i < base; i++) {
            ret[base - 1 - i] = (1 << i & number) != 0;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
[false, false]
[false, true]
[true, false]
[true, true]
```